# Why are Microsoft Hotfixes password protected?

Tags: password, windows

Why are Microsoft Hotfixes password protected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be to minimize Web distribution so that the hot fixes aren't applied to machines where they're not supposed to be.

Comment: That would be my guess, as most special hotfixes are distributed as fixes-by-request to MS directly, and probably aren't properly regression tested and they don't want blame if your servers are hosed because you installed untested software...

Comment: most (if not all) hotfixes are web distributed...

Comment: Jim B: I should say "unauthorized/validated/verified" distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess tha the reason Microsoft hotfixes are password protected is to guarantee that you have read the EULA and it provides Microsoft with a record that you have agreed to the fact that should this patch blow up your system you are doing it at your own risk.  All of the passwor dprotected hotfixes have not been mainstreamed and many times are written to address 1 specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part you have to pay for hotfixes with a valid support contract (or a one-off indecent fee). I would agree with gravyface except it would be more so that you have to pay MS for the ability to use the hotfix in addtion to the being applied to machines that they aren't ment to be applied part he mentioned.

Comment: I agree, the fees are indecent.

Comment: I've been doing this for a while and have yet to pay for a hotfix...

Comment: you most certainly do not have to pay for a hotfix unless you have contracted for legacy support (eg you paid for NT 4 support) but even then the support cost pays for the hotfix- you don't get double charged